# SSL at the root domain on heroku

Tags: ssl, heroku, dns

I've got a website with an SSL certificate for the root domain only -  example.com.au

The site runs on heroku with the dns at dnsimple.com

I want all requests to www.example.com.au to go to the canonical url, ie to example.com.au and obviously this redirection needs to be set up at the dns level so that the user doesn't get stopped with an "insecure" message.

What should i put in my DNS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want all requests to www.example.com.au to go to the canonical url, ie to example.com.au and obviously this redirection needs to be set up at the dns level so that the user doesn't get stopped with an "insecure" message.

In short: This is not possible, because aliases at DNS level will not change the hostname.

In detail:
If the user types in `www.example.com` the client (i.e. the browser) will lookup the IP for this host and it will follow any DNS aliases (like a CNAME pointing to `example.com`) during this process. But, following DNS aliases will not cause redirects inside the browser. Instead the name in the URL will stay the same and so will be the name used to verify the certificate. 
This means there is no way to do what you want at the DNS level. If you want to redirect from `https://www.example.com` to `https://example.com` you must have a certificate matching `www.example.com`.

Comment: OK, thanks.  so really to have SSL for the whole site a wildcard certificate is always needed?

Comment: You don't need wildcards if you just want to have a certificate matching `example.com` and `www.example.com`. A certificate can contain multipla names and the free certificates by StartSSL and probably others already give you the main domain and a single subdomain.

Comment: hmm, the ssl i got from geotrust only covers the root.  Think i bought the wrong thing! : (

Comment: thanks for your help here steffen.  I got this working using cloudflare free ssl pointing to the herokuapp.com url for www and then redirecting to the root domain using our EV ssl.  works really well